# How to Insert Dash Between Numbers and Text Javascript

Tags: javascript

Here are the example of input and output

Example input: SSS1111
Output: SSS-1111

Example input: SS111
Output: SS-111

Comment: your input will be always string plus number?

Comment: Is input: 1S  valid?   should that output 1-S   ? Can the input contain lowercase letters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Regular expression is a good option for such cases:**

```js
  
const str = "SSS1111abc545454xxxxxxxx66661111111XXXXX";

const separator = '_'

const result = str.match(/[a-z]+|\d+/ig).join(separator);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming strings consist of one or more letters (A-Z) followed by one or more numbers (0-9):

```
var before = 'SSS1111'
var after = s.replace( /([a-z])(\d)/i, '$1-$2' )
```

The regexp matches matches any letter `[a-z]` followed by any digit `\d` and replaces it with the letter, followed by a dash, followed by the digit.

Comment: This logic will fail when the string is something like this: 'SSS1111asdfasdf'. Using '$1-$2' will take only the first two parts of the array.

Comment: Yes, which is why I said _"Assuming strings consist of one or more letters (A-Z) followed by one or more numbers (0-9)"_. There are lots more possible variations, but I'm not going to guess which ones to consider and which to ignore; it's up to OP to let us know.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression.

```js
const str = "SSS111";
const groups = str.match(/[a-z]+|[^a-z]+/gi);
console.log(`${groups[0]}-${groups[1]}`);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use regex `/[a-z]+|[^a-z]+/gi` to get the matching values and join the array `join("-");` with the desired separator. In your case its `-`.

```js
function formatter(str) {
  return str.match(/[a-z]+|[^a-z]+/gi).join("-");
}
console.log(formatter("SSSS11111"));
console.log(formatter("SS11"));
console.log(formatter("SSSS11111SSSSS"));
console.log(formatter("S1"));
console.log(formatter("S111SS"));
console.log(formatter("SSSS11111SSSS1111"));
```

Answer (score 0):

The ***replace()*** function with ***/g*** option for regex can be used for achieving the desired result of inserting hyphen (-) between text and number.

**Syntax for replace function call:**

```
stringValue.replace( /regular_expression/g , "replacement_value" )
```

**Here is a working demonstration:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <p>Demo: Insert - between text and numbers</p>
        
        <span>Input:</span>
        <br>
        <textarea id="input" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea>
        <br>
        <button onclick="myFunction()">Demo</button>
        <hr>
        <span>Output:</span>
        <br>
        <textarea id="output" rows="10" cols="50">
            -- Output appears here --
        </textarea>

        <script>
            function myFunction() {
                var input = document.getElementById("input").value; 
                var output = input.replace(/([A-Z,a-z]+)([0-9])/g, "$1-$2");
                document.getElementById("output").value = output;
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Output:**

[image]

**More information:**

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp